# Making an exception in input for a char to quit program that only accepts integers and doesn't stop

Tags: java, exception, input, char, int

I am trying to make an exception for char(0) if it is "Q" or "q" to quit this program. It calculates a test score and it keeps allowing the user to input a test score( it doesn't end) and only accepts numbers. I want to make a exception for the letter Q or q though to quit the program.

I've tried using charAt but couldn't because it is an integer.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean run = true;
        while (run) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the test score: ");
            while (!input.hasNextInt()) {//Will run till an integer input is found
                System.out.println("Only number input is allowed!");
                System.out.print("Enter the test score: ");
                input.next();
            }

                int tS = input.nextInt();



                int sum = (10 + tS);
                System.out.println(sum);


            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to accept a string first, then using .contains() check for "q".

If it contains "q", throw exception, else parse it to int.

Something like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Test Score");
String input = sc.next();
if (input.toLowerCase().contains("q")) {
    throw new RuntimeException("The input is not numeric");
}
int tS = Integer.parseInt(input);

// do something
```

You can use a loop here to continue accepting the input.

Hope this helps. Good luck.